# Make page display 10 seconds in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await

I'm building a guessing game with Node JS. After collecting some data on the back-end, I send it to the front-end and the game starts. The data contains all 10 levels, so the game can run on a single page. Each level runs for 10 seconds. After the time is up, the user selection is sent to the server, and a result comes back. The answer is displayed, and then the content is changed to the "next level" (using the content in the big data object, therefore no refresh is needed).

I'm having some issues with having 10 levels run for 10 seconds each (or ~12 seconds with a delay for displaying the results).

This can't be done in some type of loop, since all `awaits` for each level will run at once. For instance:

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    displayPage(i);
    await timeout(10000);
    const result = await $.post(...) // gets results
    displayResults(result);
    await timeout(2000);
}
```

all the `timeout`s will run at once, and it won't work.

I thought of using a `setInterval`, but I'm not sure how to.. since I want to wait 10 seconds until checking the input, and then display the results for 2 seconds, and then move on.

For now the result I came up with is:

```
displayPage(level1);
await timeout(10000);
const result = await $.post(...)
displayResults(result);
await timeout(2000);

displayPage(level2);
await timeout(10000);
const result = await $.post(...)
displayResults(result);
await timeout(2000);

displayPage(level3);
await timeout(10000);
const result = await $.post(...)
displayResults(result);
await timeout(2000);

displayPage(level4);
await timeout(10000);
const result = await $.post(...)
displayResults(result);
await timeout(2000);

...
```

This does not seem efficient and I think there's a better way to do this, but I'm not sure how. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code works. 2 seconds are 2000 milliseconds though.

Comment: I know that it works (and thanks I'll edit that), but I was wondering if there's a better way. If I had 30 levels for instance, it would be very long and repetitive..

Comment: The first version works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
const pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

run();

async function run() {
  for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    await displayPage(i);
    const result = 'Some result';
    await displayResult(result);
  }
}

function displayPage(number) {
  text.innerText = 'Page ' + number;

  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(res, 10000);
  });
}

function displayResult(result) {
  text.innerText = 'Result: ' + result;

  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(res, 2000);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="text"><div>
```

Another solution, without promises and loops:

```js
const pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let currentPageIndex = 0;

displayPage();

function displayPage() {
  const index = currentPageIndex++;
  if (pages[index] === undefined) return;

  const pageNumber = pages[index];

  text.innerText = 'Page ' + pageNumber;

  const result = 'Some result';

  setTimeout(() => {
    displayResult(result);
  }, 10000);
}

function displayResult(result) {
  text.innerText = 'Result: ' + result;

  setTimeout(() => {
    displayPage();
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first option seems to work assuming it is wrapped within an async function:

```js
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
const testFunc = async () =>{
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log('page' , i+1 , '- question')
      await timeout(3000);
      console.log('page' , i+1 , '- answer')
      await timeout(1000);
  }
}
testFunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval on about 1000ms to create worker and add a state-machine that toggles the playing(10s) and the waiting(2s). You need a procedure that does the post call to the server and an object to keep the data(levels and stuff).

for example:

```
setInterval(funcWorker,1000,s_gameObj);



 function funcWorker(f_context){
    var l_dateNow = new Date();
    if(f_context.is_playing){
       var l_elapsed = l_dateNow.getTime() - f_context.dateLevelStart.getTime();
       if(l_elapsed.totalSeconds() >= f_context.LEVEL_TIME){

           f_context.end_level();
       }
    }else if(f_context.is_waiting_user){
       //same check as above but on the waiting start 
        ....
         f_context.next_level();


    }else if(f_context.is_waiting_server){
       //do whatever
    }
}
```

the end_level() should set the state flag in the context(game) object, to sending and send to the server. As the server returns in the response function set the state to waiting user and init the corresponding time variable to now(). The next_level() should set the state to playing and init the corresponding time variable to now() so that the timer can count. Consider the code above as a reference and not as a copy-paste resource.